# Shutdown Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010

For some reason, we need to shutdown Exchange 2010 server (two servers with DAG configuration) for 12 hours.

I want to ask is that Just go and shut down the server or any process need to concern?

Answer (score 4):

Pretty much just turn them off. First I'd shut down the passive Mailbox server, then do the active once the passive is completely down. If it's a whole site shutdown and not just Exchange, make sure you turn off your Domain Controller last.

When it comes to turning it all back on, follow the same procedure in reverse. Domain Controller first, Active Mailbox server then passive. Once your Mailbox servers are up and running, check everything is going alright with `Test-ServiceHealth` on both your Exchange servers and check the database copies are still healthy (there's no reason they shouldn't be though). Optionally perform a manual failover, but if Exchange *says* the database copies are healthy I'm inclined to believe it.